# finding the index of an array element that is the first below a given value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vectorization

if i have a given array, say:

```
a = 0.1333
    0.2667
    0.0667
    0.5333
```

and i want to find the value that is the closest to, but still less than:

```
b = 0.29
```

what is the best way to do this? the way I have been doing it so far is:

```
% add extra column for indices and sort by values
A = [(1:length(a))', a];
A = sortrows(A, 2);

% iterate along value column of A
for ii = 1:length(A)
    if A(ii,2) < b
        continue
    else
        ii = ii - 1;
        break
    end
end

% get corresponding value from index column in this case 2
idx = A(ii,1);
```

this gives me the outcome i am looking for, however it feels a bit "hacky" and not at all "matlabby".. can someone please suggest how i can improve this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution assumes that elements of `a` are always positive. 
If no elements smaller than `t` is found the smallest element of the array is returned instead as desired.

```
a = [0.1333 0.2667 0.0667 0.5333]; 
t = 0.29;

% a2 is a copy of a but where elements bigger or equal to t are set to opposite value
a2 = a;
a2(a >= t) = -a2(a >= t);

% find closest to 't' in 'a' that are below 't' - that is the maximum of the elements of a2
[~, idx] = max(a2);
result = a(idx);

% print result
disp(result)
disp(idx)
```

Comment: i was after the index of that value, but i can do that just by changing the 5th line of your code to [~,result] = max(a(a < t)); i think.. thanks!

Comment: @guskenny83 unfortunately that will only give you the index in the array of elements smaller than t.

Comment: oh, of course.. is there any way i can preserve the original index?

Comment: is there a way, using your method, that if t is less than the smallest element, that it can pick the index of the smallest element? currently, it is just picking index 1..

Comment: can it be assumed that elements of a are positive?

Comment: Yes. And that they always add to 1